# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I have these routes defined in my routes.php:

```
Route::post('/register', 'Auth\AuthController@Register');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@Login');
Route::get('/verify/{$key}', 'Auth\AuthController@Verify');
```

The first two works fine. But for some reason the third one [ /verify/{$key} ] throws a NotFoundHttpException.

The verify route calls the Verify() function in my AuthController as shown below.

```
 public function Verify($key)
    {
        $user = User::Where('verification_code', $key);

        if(!$user)
        {
            flash()->error('Error Occurred in verification.');
            return redirect('/login');
        }

        $user->verified = 1;
        $user->verification_code = null;
        $user->save;

        flash()->success('Account Successfully Verified.');
        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

When calling the php artisan route:list from the terminal the verify/{key} shows up.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is that a `GET` or `POST` request?

Comment: GET, I send a verification email to the user with a link, example: www.example.com/verify/key_here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

`Route::get('/verify/{$key}', 'Auth\AuthController@Verify');`

to

```
Route::get('/verify/{key}', 'Auth\AuthController@Verify');
```

You don't have to add `$` along with the variable in the route.